# Change class name of a img tag in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to change a class name in my img tag

```
<img src="img/nex2.jpeg" class="name">
```

Now on a hover function in jquery I want to add a class name to it.
So after hovering this tag should look like

```
<img src="img/nex2.jpeg" class="name secondname">
```

And once again on removal it should change to

```
<img src="img/nex2.jpeg" class="name">
```

Comment: Here are the docs and examples https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: It seriously looks like you might want to use css here if you want specific styling for hovered elements

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what you need:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('img.name').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('secondname');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('secondname');
    });
});
```

Or better to use CSS:

```
img.name:hover {
   // do your styling here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("img").hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass('second');
  }, function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass('second');
  }
);
```

```css
.second {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/200/200/1" class="name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:


The Complete Code in JavaScript goes like this:

This gives you complete freedom to do any styling using JavaScript and is faster than jQuery.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addClass()
        {
          document.getElementById("apple").className += " secondname";
        }
function removeClass()
        {
        //replaces all classes with initial class
          document.getElementById("apple").className = "name";
        }

        window.onload = function()
        {
            document.getElementById("apple").addEventListener( 'mouseover' , addClass );
            document.getElementById("apple").addEventListener( 'mouseout' , removeClass );
        }
    </script>
    ...
    <img src="img/nex2.jpeg" id="apple" class="name">
```

Remember that using CSS is fastest:

```
img.name:hover
{
//paste all styles of class name secondname
}
```

This way you don't have to create two classes. Only name class is enough.

Rest goes with your styling, it's up to you how you style.